# We want to check if a video is uploaded to JW CMS

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

We have a scenario in which a third party will be adding a video under a specified tag and we have to check the tag periodically using automation if a new video is added to the tag or not and then execute further steps.
I was not able to find any apis which would return me the videos/list of videos under a tag.

Comment: Where are you uploding the videos , JW CMS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by JW CMS you mean our platform, we do have a way to this using our API:

http://apidocs.jwplayer.com/methods/videos/list.html